# C# - Using XmlRoot and XmlElement to receive Xml Node Values in Model

Tags: c#

I have been trying to receive the Xml Node values in my model using the WCF Service.  I am posting the XML to my service, however, I am unable to receive the values as I have tried `Console.WriteLine()` but it did not display anything. Am I doing something wrong? 
This is my XML:

```
<query>
    <Username>test1</username>
    <Password>pass1</Password>
</query>
```

This is my model:

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "query")]
    public class XmlCls
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Username")]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my Service:

```cs
public void Login(XmlCls xmlCls)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + xmlCls.username);
    Console.WriteLine("Password: " + xmlCls.password);
}
```

Service Interface:

```cs
    [ServiceContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Login", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        void Login(XmlCls xmlCls);
    }
```

Someone please let me know if this is even possible. If not, I will just have to receive XML as string in my Service instead of using a model.

Comment: When you say "did not display anything", what do you mean by that? Does it display "Username: " or nothing? Do you get an error? If it displays nothing, maybe its because you are trying to call "voidLogin()" when your service method is just called "Login()"

Comment: @RatzMouze have edited! its `void Login()`. It just displayed "Username: " and "Password: " and then an error was thrown saying that the object was instantiated with null.